# Splitting a file on sentence delimiters

Tags: vim

I want to go to line 1508, jump to the begin of the next sentence, select everything from cursor position to the begin, write the selection to a file and delete the selection. However the execution seems to be stopped before the write operation:

```
:execute "1508" . "normal! )hvgg" . "'<,'>w /tmp/chunk.txt" . "normal! gvd"
```

Where is the error?

Answer (score 1):

`'<,'>w /tmp/chunk.txt` is a command line mode, err, command, not a normal mode command.

Comment: How to correct it so that it works?

Comment: Add `:...<cr>` around it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know the problem:

```
:help :normal
```

says

> ...  This command cannot be followed by another command...

and after I changed my code to:

```
:execute "1508" . "normal! )hvgg" | execute "'<,'>w /tmp/chunk.txt" | execute "normal! gvd"
```

it works as expected.

Comment: That's another way to do it, yes.  Except you can omit the middle `execute`.  You can further streamline it once you understand the difference between command line mode and normal mode, and how to switch between them.